# Ignore certain WCF services from WCF trace logs

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

The application I am building exposes several WCF services (A, B).  Internally, it consumes several other WCF services running on our internal network (X, Y).

Using WCF message logging, I wish to **only** log traffic between our services A, B and the external clients who call them.

No data between my services (A,B) and the backend services (X,Y) should be logged by WCF.

Filtering via system.serviceModel/diagnostics/messageLogging/filters was partially successful with:

```
    <filters>
      <add nodeQuota="10" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        /s:Envelope/s:Header/*[contains(text(),"MyServiceA")]
      </add>
      <add nodeQuota="10" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">
        /s:Envelope/s:Header/a:Action[contains(text(),"MyServiceA")]
      </add>
    </filters>
```

This however fails to capture responses from our service, as SOAP *responses* do not contain text to filter on.

The WCF MessageLogTraceRecord *does* contain the SOAP Action, but I can not seem to construct a filter to access it:

```
<MessageLogTraceRecord>
  <Addressing xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace>
     <Action>http://opia.api.translink.com.au/ApiLocationService/2012/04/IApiLocationService/ResolveInputServiceFaultFault</Action>
  </Addressing>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <s:Body>
        ...
```

WCF message logging and end to end tracing are enabled with all options set to true. ActivityTracing and Warning level logging are enabled.

Comment: You would like to filter because you are concerned about the file size or noise? MS Service Trace Viewer UI is pretty good at filtering.

Comment: Mainly noise. The "inner" services are extremely chatty, one call to our service wraps 30+ calls to theirs. The internal service interface is however well tested and no changes to it can be made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<filters>
      <add nodeQuota="10" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        /s:Envelope/s:Header/*[contains(text(),"MyServiceA")]
      </add>
      <add nodeQuota="10" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">
        /s:Envelope/s:Header/a:Action[contains(text(),"http://opia.api.translink.com.au/ApiLocationService/2012/04/IApiLocationService/ResolveInputServiceFaultFault")]
      </add>
    </filters>
```

Replaced the text "MyServiceA" in action filter with the URL in MessageLogTraceRecord > Action